# access textfield with like condition jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drupal

i have few textfields in my php form.


i want to handle the keypress of those textboxes in which id is ending with "-code" and "-case".How can i do it using jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[id$="-code"]').keypress(function() {

});
```

or

```
$('input[id$="-case"]').keypress(function() {

});
```

or even

```
$('input[id$="-code"], input[id$="-case"]').keypress(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

eg:`$('input[id$="-code"], input[id$="-case"]')`

Answer (score 2):

see [Attribute Ends With Selector [name$="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
$('input[id$="-code"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
$('textarea[id*="-code"]', 'textarea[id*="-case"]').keypress(
    //do whatever
);
```

This uses the [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

Comment: Pretty sure there's no `<textbox>` tag in standard HTML :)